# QuickBooks web API - using consolibyte PHP framework. - customer's billing address query?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am trying to create a php application that will sync data to QuickBooks. I am using the consolibyte PHP framework/examples. The examples are pretty good, but I am have a very hard time understanding how I can query customer data and print the customer's billing address.

Here is the sample code that works well, for printing the customer's name and id. If you have experience with this framework, I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
$clientName  = $_POST["clientName"]; 
    // Set the IPP version to v3 
    $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

    $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $customers = $CustomerService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CompanyName like '%$clientName%'");



    print '~{"response":[';
    foreach ($customers as $Customer)
    {

        $customerID = str_replace("{-", "", $Customer->getId());
        $customerID = str_replace("}", "", $customerID);

        print('{"QB_customerAddress":"'.$Customer->SHOW BILLING ADDRESS HERE.'", "QB_customerId":"' . $customerID . '", "QB_customerName":"' . $Customer->getFullyQualifiedName().'"},');
    }
    print ']}~=';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object model follows the Intuit XML/JSON schema exactly.

So, start by taking a look at Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

You'll notice from the documentation that the Customer object has a `BillAddr` object. For example, quoting from the Intuit docs:

```
BillAddr
 data type: PhysicalAddress
 description: Default billing address.
```

So, not surprisingly, you'll find that your QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer object is going to have some methods like:

```
// This returns a QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr object
$BillAddr = $Customer->getBillAddr();

// This accepts a QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr object as a parameter
$Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);
```

If you dig into Intuit's documentation further, you'll notice that the BillAddr node has these bits of data in it:

```
Line1
 data type: String
 description: First line of the address.

City
 data type: string
 description: City name.

etc. etc. etc. ...
```

So... naturally, the address object you got above has methods like:

```
$line1 = $BillAddr->getLine1();   // Get the first line of the address
$BillAddr->setLine1($line1);   // Set the first line of the address

$city = $BillAddr->getCity();   // Get the city name
$BillAddr->setCity($city);   // Set the city name 

 etc. etc. etc. ...
```

The objects literally follow EXACTLY what is shown in Intuit's documentation.
Also, did you try `print_r($Customer);`?   [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) will show you pretty much everything the object contains generally.

So, to get a full address, you'd end up with something like:

```
$billaddr = $Customer->getBillAddr();

$addr = '';
$addr .= $billaddr->getLine1() . "\n<br>";
$addr .= $billaddr->getLine2() . "\n<br>";
$addr .= $billaddr->getLine3() . "\n<br>";
$addr .= $billaddr->getCity() . ',  ' . $billaddr->getCountrySubDivisionCode() . ' ' . $billaddr->getPostalCode() . "\n<br>";
$addr .= $billaddr->getCountry();

print($addr);
```